# Storing onClick value to an array and further communication

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm building a React app which has a filter functionality but that isn't the problem here, I figured before tackling filtering directly I have to work my way up to it. I have taken a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html and used what I understood from it but now I'm no longer sure what's wrong or where to go from here.

I have a FilterContainer(parent) component which renders the Filter(child) components. Each Filter component is a list of filters making me have to do the functionality in the parent instead of the child since the Filters are separate from eachother.

When a user clicks on one of the filters I want to store the value of the clicked element into an array and then use that array to filter out the apartments that should be displayed. My Javascript knowledge is limited so I can't seem to handle this issue on my own.

Right now, when I click on one of the Filter buttons nothing happens and the console.log is not outputting anything meaningful.

[image: This is what it looks like on the app]

This is the Filter(child) component

```js
var Filter = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      props: []
    };
  },
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div id={this.props.id} className="filterCloud quarter-section">
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue, i) {
            return <li onClick={this.props.onClick} key={i}> {listValue} </li>;
          }.bind(this))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

And this is the FilterContainer(parent) component

```js
const FilterContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selected: [] /* Holds the filters the user clicked, needs to get updated every time a filter is interacted with */
    };
  },
  handleClick(i) {
    this.setState({ clicked: i });
    var index = this.state.selected.indexOf(i);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.state.selected.push(i);
    } else {
      this.state.selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(this.state);
  },
  render () {
    var filters = []; {/* Doesnt filter any apartments to display them on initial load */}
    var boundClick = this.handleClick;
    return (
      <section id="filterContainer" className="container">
        <Filter
          onClick={boundClick}
          id="kvartFilter"
          name={'Kvart'}
          filterList={[
            'Šubićevac', 'Meterize', 'Baldekin', 'Vidici', 'Rokići', 'Grad'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={boundClick}
          id="cijenaFilter"
          name={'Cijena'}
          filterList={[
            '< 600kn', '600kn - 700kn', '700kn - 800kn', '800kn - 900kn', '> 900kn'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={boundClick}
          id="osobeFilter"
          name={'Broj osoba'}
          filterList={[
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={boundClick}
          id="kvadraturaFilter"
          name={'Kvadratura'}
          filterList={[
            '40m - 60m', '60m - 70m', '70m - 80m', '> 80m'
        ]} />
      </section>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: first you should send the index in the onClick in your Filter component : onClick={() => {this.props.onClick(i)}}

Comment: then I think `var boundClick = this.handleClick;` is useless. You can use directly `<Filter onClick={handleClick}`

Comment: @oliv37, did what you suggested, also moved the handleClick inside the render function and added the `.bind(this)` to fix the scope. now the `console.log(this.state)` inside the handleClick is outputting arrays but only up to the index of 6 -> http://prntscr.com/c1wfsb and also it isnt noticing the difference between the Filters, it just keeps going from 0-6 no matter where i click

Comment: No need to move the handleClick function. Maybe the handleClick function is not correct, what do you want to store in your selected array. Can you give us an example.

Comment: @oliv37, i want to store the filters that have been selected. e.g. Before the user clicks anything display all apartments, when the user clicks on Grad, 700kn - 800kn, 4, 60m - 70m (for example), only the apartments with those properties are displayed, meaning, those 4 values are stored into the selected array and then passed on where it needs to be passed. Right now I cant do that part, when I click on something, nothing meaningful happens.

Comment: so you need to pass the listValue in the onClick function. Currently you are sending the index it's non sence. Try onClick={() => {this.props.onClick(listValue)}}

Comment: @oliv37, the listValue works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @oliv37 I am answering my own question for future reference.

Changes made:

- removed the `var boundClick = this.handleClick;`
- edited `onClick={boundClick}` in the Filter component to `onClick={this.handleClick}`
- removed the `this.setState({ clicked: i });`, was redundant
- changed the onClick output in the Filter component to `return <li onClick = {() => {this.props.onClick(listValue)}} key={i}> {listValue} </li>;`

Here are the updated components

Filter component

```js
var Filter = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      props: []
    };
  },
  render() {

    return (
      <div id={this.props.id} className="filterCloud quarter-section">
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue, i) {
            return <li onClick = {() => {this.props.onClick(listValue)}} key={i}> {listValue} </li>;
          }.bind(this))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

FilterContainer component

```js
const FilterContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selected: [] /* Holds the filters the user clicked, needs to get updated every time a filter is interacted with */
    };
  },
  handleClick(filterValue) {
    var index = this.state.selected.indexOf(filterValue);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.state.selected.push(filterValue);
    } else {
      this.state.selected.splice(index, filterValue);
    }
    console.log(this.state);
  },
  render () {
    var filters = []; {/* Doesnt filter any apartments to display them on initial load */}
    return (
      <section id="filterContainer" className="container">
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="kvartFilter"
          name={'Kvart'}
          filterList={[
            'Šubićevac', 'Meterize', 'Baldekin', 'Vidici', 'Rokići', 'Grad'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="cijenaFilter"
          name={'Cijena'}
          filterList={[
            '< 600kn', '600kn - 700kn', '700kn - 800kn', '800kn - 900kn', '> 900kn'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="osobeFilter"
          name={'Broj osoba'}
          filterList={[
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="kvadraturaFilter"
          name={'Kvadratura'}
          filterList={[
            '40m - 60m', '60m - 70m', '70m - 80m', '> 80m'
        ]} />
      </section>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, I would recommend to rename the handleClick argument **i** by **filterValue** to clarify your code. It will be easier to understand for an other developer cause the keyword **i** often refers to an index and here it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

Many things to say here.

First, you set the `clicked` state property but you didn't define it before nor use it after.

Second, you are directly mutating the state in your `handleClick` method by calling `slice` and `push` directly on the `state`.

Third, `setState()` is asynchronous, don't expect the changes to be immediately applied (a `console.log` statement won't display what you're expecting).

Look at this working snippet below :

```js
const FilterContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selected: [] /* Holds the filters the user clicked, needs to get updated every time a filter is interacted with */
    };
  },
  handleClick(name) {
    var index = this.state.selected.indexOf(name);
    this.setState(function(state) {
      var selected = index === -1 ? (
        state.selected.concat([name])
      ) : (
        state.selected.filter(function(filter, i) { return index !== i })
      );
      return {
        selected: selected
      }
    });
  },
  render () {
    console.log(this.state);
    var filters = []; {/* Doesnt filter any apartments to display them on initial load */}
    return (
      <section id="filterContainer" className="container">
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="kvartFilter"
          name={'Kvart'}
          filterList={[
            'Šubićevac', 'Meterize', 'Baldekin', 'Vidici', 'Rokići', 'Grad'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="cijenaFilter"
          name={'Cijena'}
          filterList={[
            '< 600kn', '600kn - 700kn', '700kn - 800kn', '800kn - 900kn', '> 900kn'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="osobeFilter"
          name={'Broj osoba'}
          filterList={[
            '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'
        ]} />
        <Filter
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          id="kvadraturaFilter"
          name={'Kvadratura'}
          filterList={[
            '40m - 60m', '60m - 70m', '70m - 80m', '> 80m'
        ]} />
      </section>
    )
  }
});

var Filter = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      props: []
    };
  },
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div id={this.props.id} className="filterCloud quarter-section">
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue, i) {
            return <li onClick={() => this.props.onClick(listValue)} key={i}> {listValue} </li>;
          }.bind(this))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<FilterContainer/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

BONUS : You shouldn't be using index as `key` because if you change the number of possible filters (maybe via some sort of facets search), react will struggles with those keys and won't reconcile some DOM elements properly, ending up in hard to find bugs.